# vsftpd on rhel 7.4 disallowing write & modify Ask

Tags: ftp, redhat-enterprise-linux, vsftpd

I've successfully installed & configured vsftp. I've created a user (joe) & companion group (joes).

My user 'joe' can create, update, & delete files in it's 'home' directory without error WHEN logged in via ssh. Joe's home directoy has been set to /var/www/site via usermod -d.  Joe can CRUD any files in /tmp, /home/joe, & /var/www/site when logged into the OS via ssh. After checking this I set the joe's shell to 'noshell' via usermod -s

joe's local directory permissions: `drwxrwxr-x. 2 joe joe   27 Jun  8 10:05 site`

The Joe can successfully login vsftpd using FileZilla. But the Joe cannot drop files to it's home directory using FileZilla. Joe can get files from the ftp hosted directory.

Here is the current procedure I'm creating to accomplish this task.

```
# yum install vsftpd
# service vsftpd stop
# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.userlist
```

add: joe

```
# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

add/edit:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
local_umask=022
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

then

```
# useradd -d /var/www/site -s /usr/sbin/nologin joe
# passwd joe
# chown -R joe /var/www/site
# chmod 775 /var/www/site
# vi /etc/shells
```

if necessary, add: /usr/sbin/nologin

```
# addgroup joes
# usermod -G joes joe
# service vsftpd start
```

Starting vsftpd is successful and without errors.

What does it take to configure vsftp to allow joe to load files from a remote?

Comment: I don’t understand. You have an ordinary, local user account (let’s say it is `joe`), and, when Joe logs in as `joe` via ssh, he has full read / write / delete permission in `/home/joe`.  But when Joe logs in to the FTP server (vsftp) — is he even in `/home/joe`, or is he in `/var/www/site`?  Can he access `/tmp`?  Can he create files there?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man As requested

Comment: Thanks for the update; sorry for my delay in responding.  Is `joe` in the `root` group?  If yes, that’s probably worth mentioning.  If not, then it doesn’t make sense that he can create or delete files in `/var/www/site`, because the `ftpuser` user and the members of the `root` group are the only people who should have write access to that directory.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Oh, wait!  I just noticed that the `site` mode has an eleventh character, which is dot (**`.`**).  Does it have an ACL or some other security attributes?  Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: joe is in the group joe.  I only swapped 'joe' in place of every mention of 'ftpuser' in the OP at your request.  Did I mess one? Corrected.  Yes the 'ftpuser' & 'root'  would be found as confusing.

Answer (score 0):

These two things make this work:
`local_umask=777`
and
`useradd joe -d /var/www/site`
no permutation of `chown` and/or `chown` appear to affect any positive outcome